# kivy Buildozer Android build cannot find translation files

Tags: python, android, kivy, gettext, buildozer

Post building my kivy app for Android using Buildozer the run step fails as it cannot find the message files for gettext.
I have the following line in my .spec file:

```
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,mo,po,ini
```

The .mo files are in the current app dir under ./locales.

I have also included the following line in .spec:

```
source.include_patterns = locales/*
```

Finally, my code in main.py includes:

```
trans = gettext.translation('base', localedir='locales', languages=[locale.getdefaultlocale()[0][0:2]])
```

languages is set to en and an en directory is within the locales folder.

Is appears as if Buildozer is picking these up:

```
Listing '/Users/martinprater/PycharmProjects/kivy/.buildozer/android/app/locale/de'...
Listing '/Users/martinprater/PycharmProjects/kivy/.buildozer/android/app/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES'...
Listing '/Users/martinprater/PycharmProjects/kivy/.buildozer/android/app/locale/en'...
Listing '/Users/martinprater/PycharmProjects/kivy/.buildozer/android/app/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES'...
```

How can I validate if they are included in the app?
Thanks,
Martin

Comment: Add some logging to print out the details of your directory structure on the device, then read those details in the logcat stream and see if it matches what you expect.

Comment: The resulting `.apk` is actually a `zip` file. You can `unzip` it to see what is included in the `apk`.

Comment: Apart from my code only my icon is in the package.  I have tried including everything in the directory by commenting out: #source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas. Unfortunately same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the easiest way, but could solve the issue by switching to p4a native and using setup.py:

```
setup(
    ...
    package_data={'.': ['main.py', '*.kv', '*.png', 'locales/*/LC_MESSAGES/base.mo']}
)
```

Then accessing the file using pkg_resources:

```
pkg_resources.resource_filename('pkg', 'locales')
```